# Postfix policyd dual usage setup - greylisting and quotas

Tags: postfix, quota, accounting, greylisting

On our server we are using policyd 1.x together with Postfix 2.1.5 for greylisting and enforcing incoming quotas from unauthorized users (ie. mail for our domains). For this, I have set up Postfix `main.cf` like this:

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = greylisting
greylisting = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
...
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    ...
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    ...
    check_client_access pcre:/etc/postfix/checks/greylist.pcre,
```

and set up a selective greylisting configuration:

```
# greylist.pcre
/^unknown$/     greylisting
# TLDs with high spam rate
/\.(ni|ru|hu|us|si|sk|cn|jp|ro|hn|mx|br|ar|cc|ae|ee|my|tr|pt|cz)$/ greylisting
... etc
```

i.e. the SASL authentication overrides policyd. So far, this works great. However, I would now like to use policyd as well for authenticated users and set up a completely *different* rule set for these users:

For SOME unauthorized users, based on remote host name,

- greylisting,
- accounting (limit number of mails per time) with defaults,
- blacklisting,
- whitelisting.

For authorized (SASL) users,

- no greylisting,
- different user-specific outgoing mail quota with default,
- no blacklisting,
- no whitelisting.

So far, I think I have to run another instance of policyd with different SQL database and configuration file.

Is this true or is there a way to configure a single instance of policyd to use different rulesets based on remote hostname AND SASL authentication status?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in policyd v2 (cluebringer). You can define rules for each policy (1 policy for incoming email, another policy for outgoing, another for SASL). And then you can assign different policyd components (grelist, SPF, quota) to each policy.

http://wiki.policyd.org/documentation

Comment: Do you have a working example configuration? I have tried cluebringer but despite quite decent documentation and even a web UI, I don't think I have figured it out completely.

Comment: I am using only quotas - based on this post: http://lists.policyd.org/pipermail/users_lists.policyd.org/2012-October/004002.html but also the policyd wiki cleared few things for me.